# Integrable Systems-Description

Tags: definition, integrable-systems

I am relatively new to the topic of integrable systems and I came across the following description:

"Integrable systems share a fundamental property which is related to the geometry of the initial phase space"

While I know what a phase space is, I do not understand what the above description means. A simple explanation will be appreciated.

Does Integrable systems focus on both linear and nonlinear systems or just the latter?

Thanks,
MGM.